# html javascript call function on load

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make something like:

```
1. 1296
2. 4624

Square root both numbers and add the result! 
Answer: ________
[Check button]
```

and open the `somewhere.html` if the answer is correct

I made this script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload=calc; 

        function calc() {
            var num1, num2, sqNum1, sqNum2, randomNum, sum, ans;
            num1=Math.floor(Math.random()*90)+10;
            num2=Math.floor(Math.random()*90)+10;
            sqNum1=num1*num1;
            sqNum2=num2*num2;
            sum=num1+num2;
            document.write("1. " + sqNum1 + "<br />");
            document.write("2. " + sqNum2 + "<br />");
            document.write("<br />");
        }

        function checkAns(form) {
            if (form.ans.value==sum) {
                location="somewhere.html";
            } else {
                alert ("Wrong answer!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Square root both numbers and add the result! <br />
    <form name='question'>
        Answer: <input name='ans' type='password'> <br />
        <input type='button' value='Check' onClick='checkAns(this.form)'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whatever I tried, it never displays this part:

```
Square root both numbers and add the result! 
Answer: ________
[Check button]
```

What is wrong with this script?

Comment: Another problem you're going to run into is you're declaring the variable `sum` inside of the `calc` function. When declaring a variable with `var` inside of a function, its scope is limited to inside of that function. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) to learn more about scope in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function calc() {
            var num1, num2, sqNum1, sqNum2, randomNum, sum, ans;
            num1=Math.floor(Math.random()*90)+10;
            num2=Math.floor(Math.random()*90)+10;
            sqNum1=num1*num1;
            sqNum2=num2*num2;
            sum=num1+num2;
            document.getElementById("sum").value = sum;

            var question = document.getElementById("question");
            var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
            var br = document.createElement('br');
            var txt = document.createTextNode("1. " + sqNum1);
            numbers.appendChild(txt);
            numbers.appendChild(br);
            var txt = document.createTextNode("2. " + sqNum2);
            numbers.appendChild(txt);
            txt.appendChild(question);
        }

        function checkAns(form) {

            if (document.getElementById("ans").value == document.getElementById("sum").value) {
                var newWin = open('somewhere.html','windowName','height=300,width=300');
            } else {
                alert ("Wrong answer!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="calc();">
    <form name='question'>
        <div id="numbers">
        </div>
        <br/>
        Square root both numbers and add the result! <br />
        <div id="question">
            Answer: <input id='ans' name='ans' type='password'> <br />
            <input type='button' value='Check' onClick='checkAns(this.form)'>
        </div>
        <input id='sum' type='hidden' value=''/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not the best answer, it is one way you can use to follow with your development

Comment: The output is correct, but the function still doesn't work well, it didn't check the answer after the button is pressed. anyway, thanks for the script that maybe can help me understand Quentin's explanation

Comment: Sorry I think that you only need to load the numbers, I didn't see the checkAns function. I will check that part

Answer (score 5):

By the time the `load` function is called, the document it in a *closed* state.

You cannot `write` to a document in a closed state, so calling `write` will call `open` for you.

Calling `open` will wipe out the existing document.

The new content is written to the new document.

Use [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML#Creating_HTML) (`createElement`, `appendChild` and friends) to edit an existing document.